# Error when creating a systemd unit for Apache Drill

Tags: systemd, apache-drill

I have installed Apache Drill and want to start it when the machine boots up. To do this, I have created the following systemd unit in `/etc/systemd/system/drill.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Start/Stop Apache Drill
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=me
Group=me
ExecStartPre==-/usr/bin/zk_up
ExecStart=/opt/apache/drill/current/bin/drillbit.sh --config /opt/apache/drill/current/conf start
ExecStop=/opt/apache/drill/current/bin/drillbit.sh stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The issue is that when I issue the command `systemctl start drill`, the service does not start completely. It seems to hang and then times out. While the process is hung, running the command `systemctl status -l drill.service` shows the status as `activating`. This is the output of the command `systemctl status -l drill.service`

```
drill.service - Start/Stop Apache Drill
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/drill.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Fri 2019-10-25 07:32:24 UTC; 55s ago
  Process: 10257 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/zk_up (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Control: 10262 (drillbit.sh)
   CGroup: /system.slice/drill.service
           ├─10262 /bin/bash /opt/apache/drill/current/bin/drillbit.sh --config /opt/apache/drill/current/conf start
           ├─10273 /bin/bash /opt/apache/drill/current/bin/drillbit.sh --config /opt/apache/drill/current/conf start
           ├─10274 find -L / -name java -type f
           └─10275 head -n 1
```

After the process fails, I see the following message displayed
`Job for drill.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status drill.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

The command `systemctl status -l drill.service` after the timeout returns the following

```
drill.service - Start/Stop Apache Drill
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/drill.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Fri 2019-10-25 07:33:54 UTC; 3min 3s ago
  Process: 10262 ExecStart=/opt/apache/drill/current/bin/drillbit.sh --config /opt/apache/drill/current/conf start (code=killed, signal=TERM)
  Process: 10257 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/zk_up (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

And when I run `journalctl -xe`, I see the following messages

```
Oct 25 07:39:17 drill-1 drillbit.sh[10774]: find: File system loop detected; ‘/sys/bus/cpu/devices/cpu0/node0/cpu1/driver/cpu2/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/PNP0303:00/physical_node/subsystem/devices/00:03/tty/ttyS0/subsystem/ttyS2/device/subsystem/devices/VMBUS:01/firmware_node/2dd1ce17-079e-403c-b352-a1921ee207ee/driver/b6650ff7-33bc-4840-8048-e0676786f393/subsystem/devices/00000000-0001-8899-0000-000000000000/host3/scsi_host/host3/subsystem/host2/device/target2:0:0/subsystem/devices/3:0:1:0/scsi_device/3:0:1:0/subsystem/2:0:0:0/device/block/sda/sda2/subsystem/sda’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/sys/bus/cpu/devices/cpu0/node0/cpu1/driver/cpu2/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/PNP0303:00/physical_node/subsystem/devices/00:03/tty/ttyS0/subsystem/ttyS2/device/subsystem/devices/VMBUS:01/firmware_node/2dd1ce17-079e-403c-b352-a1921ee207ee/driver/b6650ff7-33bc-4840-8048-e0676786f393/subsystem/devices/00000000-0001-8899-0000-000000000000/host3/scsi_host/host3/subsystem/host2/device/target2:0:0/subsystem/devices/3:0:1:0/scsi_device/3:0:1:0/subsystem/2:0:0:0/device/block/sda’.
Oct 25 07:39:17 drill-1 drillbit.sh[10774]: find: File system loop detected; ‘/sys/bus/cpu/devices/cpu0/node0/cpu1/driver/cpu2/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/PNP0303:00/physical_node/subsystem/devices/00:03/tty/ttyS0/subsystem/ttyS2/device/subsystem/devices/VMBUS:01/firmware_node/2dd1ce17-079e-403c-b352-a1921ee207ee/driver/b6650ff7-33bc-4840-8048-e0676786f393/subsystem/devices/00000000-0001-8899-0000-000000000000/host3/scsi_host/host3/subsystem/host2/device/target2:0:0/subsystem/devices/3:0:1:0/scsi_device/3:0:1:0/subsystem/2:0:0:0/device/block/sda/sda2/subsystem/sdb/bdi/subsystem/2:0/subsystem’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/sys/bus/cpu/devices/cpu0/node0/cpu1/driver/cpu2/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/PNP0303:00/physical_node/subsystem/devices/00:03/tty/ttyS0/subsystem/ttyS2/device/subsystem/devices/VMBUS:01/firmware_node/2dd1ce17-079e-403c-b352-a1921ee207ee/driver/b6650ff7-33bc-4840-8048-e0676786f393/subsystem/devices/00000000-0001-8899-0000-000000000000/host3/scsi_host/host3/subsystem/host2/device/target2:0:0/subsystem/devices/3:0:1:0/scsi_device/3:0:1:0/subsystem/2:0:0:0/device/block/sda/sda2/subsystem/sdb/bdi/subsystem’.
Oct 25 07:39:17 drill-1 drillbit.sh[10774]: find: File system loop detected; ‘/sys/bus/cpu/devices/cpu0/node0/cpu1/driver/cpu2/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/PNP0303:00/physical_node/subsystem/devices/00:03/tty/ttyS0/subsystem/ttyS2/device/subsystem/devices/VMBUS:01/firmware_node/2dd1ce17-079e-403c-b352-a1921ee207ee/driver/b6650ff7-33bc-4840-8048-e0676786f393/subsystem/devices/00000000-0001-8899-0000-000000000000/host3/scsi_host/host3/subsystem/host2/device/target2:0:0/subsystem/devices/3:0:1:0/scsi_device/3:0:1:0/subsystem/2:0:0:0/device/block/sda/sda2/subsystem/sdb/bdi/subsystem/8:0/subsystem’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/sys/bus/cpu/devices/cpu0/node0/cpu1/driver/cpu2/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/PNP0303:00/physical_node/subsystem/devices/00:03/tty/ttyS0/subsystem/ttyS2/device/subsystem/devices/VMBUS:01/firmware_node/2dd1ce17-079e-403c-b352-a1921ee207ee/driver/b6650ff7-33bc-4840-8048-e0676786f393/subsystem/devices/00000000-0001-8899-0000-000000000000/host3/scsi_host/host3/subsystem/host2/device/target2:0:0/subsystem/devices/3:0:1:0/scsi_device/3:0:1:0/subsystem/2:0:0:0/device/block/sda/sda2/subsystem/sdb/bdi/subsystem’.
Oct 25 07:39:17 drill-1 drillbit.sh[10774]: find: File system loop detected; ‘/sys/bus/cpu/devices/cpu0/node0/cpu1/driver/cpu2/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/PNP0303:00/physical_node/subsystem/devices/00:03/tty/ttyS0/subsystem/ttyS2/device/subsystem/devices/VMBUS:01/firmware_node/2dd1ce17-079e-403c-b352-a1921ee207ee/driver/b6650ff7-33bc-4840-8048-e0676786f393/subsystem/devices/00000000-0001-8899-0000-000000000000/host3/scsi_host/host3/subsystem/host2/device/target2:0:0/subsystem/devices/3:0:1:0/scsi_device/3:0:1:0/subsystem/2:0:0:0/device/block/sda/sda2/subsystem/sdb/bdi/subsystem/0:38/subsystem’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/sys/bus/cpu/devices/cpu0/node0/cpu1/driver/cpu2/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/PNP0303:00/physical_node/subsystem/devices/00:03/tty/ttyS0/subsystem/ttyS2/device/subsystem/devices/VMBUS:01/firmware_node/2dd1ce17-079e-403c-b352-a1921ee207ee/driver/b6650ff7-33bc-4840-8048-e0676786f393/subsystem/devices/00000000-0001-8899-0000-000000000000/host3/scsi_host/host3/subsystem/host2/device/target2:0:0/subsystem/devices/3:0:1:0/scsi_device/3:0:1:0/subsystem/2:0:0:0/device/block/sda/sda2/subsystem/sdb/bdi/subsystem’.
Oct 25 07:39:17 drill-1 drillbit.sh[10774]: find: File system loop detected; ‘/sys/bus/cpu/devices/cpu0/node0/cpu1/driver/cpu2/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/PNP0303:00/physical_node/subsystem/devices/00:03/tty/ttyS0/subsystem/ttyS2/device/subsystem/devices/VMBUS:01/firmware_node/2dd1ce17-079e-403c-b352-a1921ee207ee/driver/b6650ff7-33bc-4840-8048-e0676786f393/subsystem/devices/00000000-0001-8899-0000-000000000000/host3/scsi_host/host3/subsystem/host2/device/target2:0:0/subsystem/devices/3:0:1:0/scsi_device/3:0:1:0/subsystem/2:0:0:0/device/block/sda/sda2/subsystem/sdb/bdi/subsystem/8:16’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/sys/bus/cpu/devices/cpu0/node0/cpu1/driver/cpu2/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/PNP0303:00/physical_node/subsystem/devices/00:03/tty/ttyS0/subsystem/ttyS2/device/subsystem/devices/VMBUS:01/firmware_node/2dd1ce17-079e-403c-b352-a1921ee207ee/driver/b6650ff7-33bc-4840-8048-e0676786f393/subsystem/devices/00000000-0001-8899-0000-000000000000/host3/scsi_host/host3/subsystem/host2/device/target2:0:0/subsystem/devices/3:0:1:0/scsi_device/3:0:1:0/subsystem/2:0:0:0/device/block/sda/sda2/subsystem/sdb/bdi’.
```

Can anyone tell me why am I seeing these messages and what do I need to do to get it working?

If I run the command defined for the `ExecStart` parameter on my terminal itself, Apache Drill start without throwing any errors. The command `/usr/bin/zk_up` just checks if the zookeepers are running before I start Drill and as shown above, this command exits successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I closely looked at the output of the `systemctl status -l drill.service` command, I saw that the culprit that was printing the file system loop messages was the `find` command and that command was looking for `java`. I added the `JAVA_HOME` to the environment in the systemd file and it worked. My new `systemd` unit is

```
[Unit]
Description=Start/Stop Apache Drill
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=me
Group=me
Environment="JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/current"
ExecStartPre==-/usr/bin/zk_up
ExecStart=/opt/apache/drill/current/bin/drillbit.sh --config /opt/apache/drill/current/conf start
ExecStop=/opt/apache/drill/current/bin/drillbit.sh stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

where `/opt/java/current` is where my `$JAVA_HOME` is.